# c# aspx how to perform a split on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, frontend

I am working with a datatable to fill a table with bootstrap.
One of the fields is of type string and in it data is saved separated by pipe.
I am trying to split the page, but it gives me an error, it is difficult for me to pass them already separated from the .cs to the page

```
foreach (string t in tipoDoc)
{
  string pathFinal = path + t;
  if (target.Contains(pathFinal))
  {
    row["Protocolos"] += pathPDF + target + ".pdf | ";
  }
}
```

What I need is to be able to insert in a table cell on the page, and represent them in it

Comment: What do you mean by split the page? How are you passing the DataTable to the aspx page? Are you using Javascript at all? Also, what line are you getting the thrown exception?

Comment: I'm populating the data as follows <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% # Eval ("foo")%>' />

Comment: You could try dynamically creating the html table and labels from the c# datatable from the backend.